# Improving performance of my library prototype

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm working on a small jQuery-esque library for a project of mine and everything works great so far but I got some performance problems and I can't seem to figure out why although I've some ideas, but first, here's the code in question (reduced to show the actual problem):

Demo: http://jsbin.com/umemot/1/edit

```
(function(doc, win) {

  // Utils:

  var AP = Array.prototype;

  function _toArray(obj) {
    return AP.slice.call(obj);
  }

  function _curry(fn, that) {
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(that || arguments[0], AP.slice.call(arguments));
    };
  }

  function _flatten(arr) {
    return AP.concat.apply([], arr);
  }

  function _uniq(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(el, i) {
      return arr.indexOf(el) == i;
    });
  }

  function _removeEmpty(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(v) { return v; });
  }

  // Proto:

  function Lib(selector) {
    this.el = this._init(selector);
  }

  function lib(selector) {
    return new Lib(selector);
  }

  // Lib:

  Lib.prototype = {

    _init: function(selector) {
      return _toArray(doc.querySelectorAll(selector));
    },

    _with: function(fn) {
      var result = [];
      this.each(function() { result.push(fn.call(this, this)); });   
      this.el = _removeEmpty(_uniq(_flatten(result)));
      return this;
    },

    _matches: function(selector) {
      return this._with(function() {
        var parent = _toArray(this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(selector));
        return ~parent.indexOf(this) && this;
      });
    },

    each: function(fn) {
      return this.el.forEach(_curry(fn)), this;
    },

    find: function(selector) {
      return this._with(function() {
        return _toArray(this.querySelectorAll(selector));
      });
    },

    children: function(selector) {
      return this._with(function() {
        return _toArray(this.children);
      });
    },

    filter: function(selector) {
      return this._matches(selector);
    }

  };

  win._ = lib;

}(document, window));
```

The I use it very much like jQuery:

```
_('#outer').find('div').children().filter('a');
```

The issue I'm having is a big performance drop compared to jQuery as you can see here http://jsperf.com/lib-vs-jquery-69.

Here's what I'm thinking:

- All those ES5 array methods are slowing it down
- Some kind of garbage collection issue? Maybe I'm leaking something?
- Is the `_matches` method efficient enough?

Can all of the above cause performance to be 60% slower than jQuery or is my implementation just wrong? Any ideas?

**Edit:** I'm testing in other browsers and seems to be a "big issue" just with Chrome...although Opera says it's 20% slower, an Firefox only 3%...

Comment: Performance and optimization questions are generally better off in codereview.stackexchange.com.  I'd suggest benchmarking each method of your test vs. jQuery to see which one offers the most issue to work on.  My guess (without testing) would the `.filter()` operation.

Comment: I've done that already, yes `filter` (or `_matches`) seems to be the one that stresses the most but seems efficient enough. I tried adding a temporary class an using `querySelectorAll` just once on `document` but performance didn't improve. I guess I'll have to take this to codereview then.

Comment: Also, it seems so random at times, I tried with a bunch of other methods (not in this example) including filtering at the end and some times jQuery is slower.